# How to fix the warning and error messages after the installation of SuiteCRM - 7.12.5 in XAMPP?

Tags: php, suitecrm

While installing SuiteCRM on my system, I am getting the errors and  warnings in the SuiteCRM dashboard. Tried to remove this by just write error_reporting(0) in the index.php. It hidden the warnings but fatal error displayed in certain pages of the SuiteCRM dashboard. I have XAMPP Control Panel V3.3.0  with php 8.1.5 and phpMyAdmin 5.1.3. Can anyone suggest me What to do ? Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although the linked question is asking for the opposite, it lists the relevant settings; you just want 0/off instead of 1/on.

Comment: Also, note that the title and body of your question ask very different things: **hiding** all errors is trivial, but **fixing** them requires knowing what they actually are and changing something, so we can't help without seeing them. [This reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/157957) will be a good place to start, though.

Comment: Can you share those fatal errors because OOTB SuiteCRM doesn't have fatal errors?